# Why does the value attribute of my <input> tag cause a redirect?

Tags: html, django, forms

I new to programming and I am reading this Django book and it says that in the template that codes for login page, the value attribute of input can redirect the user to the main page after the user log in successfully.

When I want to find out more I see the HTML documentation but it says the value attribute accepts data to be submitted to the server however it does not say how it causes a redirect in the URL.

May I please know how does the value attribute cause a redirect to the URL?

I added the Django tag but I am not sure if it’s a Django question.

[image: the photo of the code]
[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Post CODE, not pictures of code

Comment: The "redirect" (processing of the URL) takes place on the server. It has nothing to do with the HTML which is just collecting parameters for the server code

Comment: @mplungjan so the django takes the URL given here and redirects to the URL? So if django is not used and there’s just HTML there would be no redirect?

Comment: Well, you COULD have a GET of another HTML page (action="page2.html") , But a POST goes via the server

Comment: @mplungjan without using get but just using this not possible right?

Comment: You cannot POST to an HTML page

Comment: [RTM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form is submitted back to the server the value of the "name" attribute tells the server the name of the variable to put that value into.

In this case an input with the name of "next" has specific meaning to Django itself for authentication forms.  In this case being used to tell Django which URL to redirect to if the authentication is successful.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/